# OSX: modifying files with proper rights

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems, rights

I am trying to modify (delete, replace, ...) files which required admin rights to be modified.
For the moment, the operation just fails.
How to:

- Know that special rights are required
- Ask the user to grant the application temporary to perform this operation
- Run the operation with the given rights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995).